# Can I have a custom URI protocol open the "default PDF viewer" on a user's machine to a specific remote file from a browser?

Tags: pdf, registry, uri, acrobat

I would like to hypothetically have the URL annotate://\REMOTESERVER1\path\to\remote\file.pdf open the default PDF reader on a Windows user's machine with the *remote file* opened rather than downloading and opening it locally. I know the following works from the command line:

```
start \\REMOTESERVER1\path\to\remote\file.pdf
```

I've added keys to the registry using these instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I've tried the following in the "command" value:

- Register it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" with no variables - successfully launches Acrobat
- Register it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" with the full path to the document hardcoded - successfully launches the document in Acrobat
- Register it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "%1" (both with and without quotes) - fails. Acrobat says the syntax to the path is invalid. I have tried various URI encoding schemes and escapes in the slashes but maybe I'm missing something?
- Register different combinations of "start" (with/without quotes) and the full file path - fails; doesn't even try to open Acrobat.

Note:

- These will all be Windows users
- These users will all be on a VPN able to access this remote file
- These users will all be using Adobe Acrobat however they may be using different versions, hence wanting to load the "default PDF viewer"

It doesn't look like Acrobat has anything built in to capture a custom URI protocol. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is to be accessed using HTTP, Adobe Reader doesn't work with a URL as a parameter. So complementing retrotube answer, the open command could be writen as:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\adobe]
@="URL:PDF Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\adobe\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\adobe\shell]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\adobe\shell\open]
@="Open with Adobe Acrobat"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\adobe\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /v:on /c \"SET _invocation=%1 & SET _sfile=!_invocation:~6! & SET _dfile=!temp!\\!random!-!random!-!random!.pdf & curl -o !_dfile! !_sfile! & start \"\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe\" !_dfile!"
```